# How to delete a directory using cmd

Tags: authentication, cmd, command

i'm new at cmd and this is the first code i've ever written using the program. There are parts of this code i haven't written myself.

My problem is that i'm trying to delete a folder using CMD but i can't get it to work.

I'm using this command:

```
    RM /S /Q "directory"
```

In this code

```
    cls 
@ECHO OFF
color 02
title ija4779fc 
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK 
if NOT EXIST MyFolder(2) goto MDMyFolder(2) 
:CONFIRM 
echo Are you sure to lock this folder? (Y/N) 
set/p "cho=>" 
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==n goto END 
if %cho%==N goto END 
echo THIS IS NOT AN OPTION.
goto CONFIRM 
:LOCK 
ren MyFolder(2) "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
echo Folder locked 
goto UNLOCK
:UNLOCK 
echo ENTER PASSWORD:
set/p "pass=>" 
if NOT %pass%== ija4779fc goto FAIL 
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" MyFolder 
echo UNLOCKED
goto PAUSE
:FAIL
Color 04
echo INCORRECT PASSWORD
DEL /S /Q "MyFolder(2)"
echo S
echo FILES DELETED
echo SYSTEM SHUTDOWN
goto end
:CORRECT
echo
:PAUSE
PAUSE
:MDMYFOLDER(2)
:END
end
MD Myfolder(2)
```

Thnx for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to delete a subdirectory it to use RMDIR (or RD short short). The system documentation for RD is as follows (generated using `RD /?`)

```
Removes (deletes) a directory.

RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path

    /S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
            in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
            tree.

    /Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S
```